# SpringBoot override I18N messages.properties for jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, internationalization

I have a spring boot project which should use default values for `application.properties` and the language resource bundle `message.properties`. Overriding `application.properties` is easy and well documented, however I have a usecase which requires me to override the localized messages of `message.properties` when executing the `.jar` - the user of my jar should be able to write their own localized (greeting, warning, error, ...) messages.

Comment: Provide the proper pattern for the Spring Messages. The default will only read from the classpath and not some other location.

Comment: I cant follow you @M, could you make an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot by default configures the [`ResourceBundlerMessageSource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ResourceBundleMessageSource.html) which by convention can and will only load I18N files from the classpath. Simply because it is build around `ResourceBundle` which can only come from the classpath.

You can configure your own `MessageSource` like the [`ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html) which supports full Spring resource loading. With that you can specify something like `file:/opt/your-app/messages`, which will point to a resource on the file system. You can reuse the existing properties from the `spring.messages` namespace if you re-use the `MessagesProperties` class in your configuration.

```java
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.messages")
public MessageSourceProperties messageSourceProperties() {
    return new MessageSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource(MessageSourceProperties properties) {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    if (StringUtils.hasText(properties.getBasename())) {
        messageSource.setBasenames(StringUtils
                .commaDelimitedListToStringArray(StringUtils.trimAllWhitespace(properties.getBasename())));
    }
    if (properties.getEncoding() != null) {
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding(properties.getEncoding().name());
    }
    messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(properties.isFallbackToSystemLocale());
    Duration cacheDuration = properties.getCacheDuration();
    if (cacheDuration != null) {
        messageSource.setCacheMillis(cacheDuration.toMillis());
    }
    messageSource.setAlwaysUseMessageFormat(properties.isAlwaysUseMessageFormat());
    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(properties.isUseCodeAsDefaultMessage());
    return messageSource;
}
```

**NOTE:** This is basically what the auto-configuration does for the `ResourceBundleMessageSource` and I copied it here with a slight modification for the `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`.